# Are there any advantages to buying a game on the Mac App Store (MAS) instead of Steam?

Tags: steam, macos, version-differences, mac-app-store

I was looking at *The Baconing* on the Mac App Store (MAS) and found that it is also available on Steam. Besides the price difference is there any other reason I would want the MAS version over the Steam version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a SteamWorks title like *The Baconing*, if you buy it on Steam, you get both the Windows and Mac versions.

The catch is that Steam requires you to have an Internet connection, at least periodically, to verify that you own the game.

As far as I'm aware, those are the only differences.

Comment: Depending on the game, some games have a 'Special Steam Version', but I don't know how many with that have Steamplay (The example that's springing to mind is Tropico 4, but that's Windows-only).

Comment: Also Steamworks for syncing of saves across machines. Not present in all games, but, in my experience, in a disproportionate number of cross platform titles.

Comment: @Margaret: The Baconing is a SteamPlay title (I checked before answering).

Comment: Powerlord: Ah, I apparently didn't read closely enough and missed that @Steve was looking at a specific game.  I was more contributing towards a general "Why Steam over x?" query...

Comment: @Margaret: Well, it wasn't in the question title or tags, so I can see why you might have missed it.  Actually, I edited my answer to mention SteamWorks to make it more generic.

Comment: What about leader boards?

Answer (score 1):

I was just about to ask the same question. I haven't bought any game on Steam. But from my experience with the App Store and iTunes Store, they often have discounts on big events and public holidays (Christmas, Labour Day, etc).

IMHO, SteamPlay titles sometimes cost more. yes, you get both Mac & PC version. But in my case, I only play in one platform at a time. I play the heavy games on PC, and then the more casual games on my Mac Air.